# How to convert SRTM's Lat/Lon to Landsat's utm reference system in GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, landsat, utm, srtm

SRTM data is given in Lat/Lon coordinates, while Landsat is given in UTM coordinates. Is there a way to reproject the SRTM data into the Landsat CRS in GDAL (Python)?

Comment: Yes. For example with gdalwarp http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html which is also pythonized https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc59.1_utilities_as_a_library.

Comment: I have python's gdal installed but it seems that there is no function `gdal.Warp()`..

Comment: I am not sure which GDAL version has the support. Trunk an least does and this autotest script may be useful for you https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/autotest/utilities/test_gdalwarp_lib.py.

Answer (score 2):

The tool in gdal that can reproject your data is [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html).

With gdalwarp, you must provide the source and target coordinate systems with -s_srs and -t_srs, respectively. In your case, it would be

gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG 326xx your_source
_file_name your_dest_file_name, where xx are the numbers of the UTM zone.

Note  that you can get the coordinate system automatically if your have images everywhere in the world (see, e.g., [GDAL/Python: How do I get coordinate system name from SpatialReference?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60371/gdal-python-how-do-i-get-coordinate-system-name-from-spatialreference))

Comment: The code reported in the link you provided does not work in my case (it seems that `srs.IsProjected()` is returning `False`). Is there any way to automate this within a Python script?