# Get UTM zone with GeoPandas from a shapefile

Tags: geopandas, epsg, utm

I want to know to which UTM zone belong a shapefile.

With GeoPandas I can read a shapefile and know its EPSG code:

`import geopandas as gpd
dataframe = gpd.read_file('shapefile.shp')
print(dataframe.crs)`

> > {'init': 'epsg:32616'}

Is there anyway to get the UTM zone with GeoPandas or to transform the EPSG code to UTM zone? for example epsg:32616 would be the UTM zone 16 N.

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60371/gdal-python-how-do-i-get-coordinate-system-name-from-spatialreference

Comment: Not sure if it's currently possible see https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/543

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at an open issue [#543](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/543) on geopandas GitHub, it appears that what you want to do is not yet possible.

As you have fiona then you can use:

```
import fiona


source_crs_wkt = fiona.open(shapedata).meta['crs_wkt']
print(source_crs_wkt)
```

To give for example from an [EPSG:4326](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326) projected shapefile:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

and if you have osr

```
import osr


srs = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=source_crs_wkt)
print(srs.GetAttrValue('geogcs'))
```

will give:

```
WGS 84
```

Comment: WGS 84 is not the information that I wanted but I have checked that at least with my shapefile it also prints the UTM zone: 'PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 16N", ... '.

Comment: what about `print(srs.GetAttrValue('projcs'))`

Comment: Yes with that I get 'WGS 84 / UTM zone 16N' which is the information I need.